# Writing PHPUnit tests for view plugins

Tags: views, 8, testing

I am trying to test custom views field & filter plugins using PHPUnit, but I keep getting dependency issues. I am curious to know if:

1. It possible to Unit test View plugins?
2. Simulate DB interactions.
3. Is it possible to inject services e.g database, request, response etc via a constructor, setter or property injection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views plugins are testable, and Drupal core has a lot of examples.  I believe most aren't UnitTestCase (or \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase), but rather KernelTestBase tests.

KTB tests will boot a minimal Drupal setup so you don't have to set up extensive mocking for dependencies, especially config and database.

Views in particular has ViewsKernelTestBase, which does basic setup for testing Views plugins.  You can use your IDE to find usages of this for example, but I know some are in web/core/modules/datetime/tests/src/Kernel/Views/

Essentially, you make a test module that has YAML for your test views.  The test declares this in its `$modules` list, along with the module that is providing the plugin.  You also define the test views, and these get imported.  You can then use the Views API in your test methods.

Then, as long as you use the new ViewsKernelTestBase, you can run it directly through PhpUnit, assuming you have your phpunit.xml setup properly.

Comment: I think @larowlan has a good tutorial on KTB testing. Not sure if this was a blog post or a Drupal Watchdog article.  If I find it, I will edit it into the answer.